# Calling the current and next item in a bash for loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I'm conducting a reiterative analysis and having to submit more than 5000 jobs to a batch system on a large computer cluster.

I'm wanting to run a bash for loop but call both the current list item and the next item in my script.  I'm not sure the best way to do this using this format:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in `cat list.txt`; 
do
    # run a bunch of code on $i (ex. Data file for 'Apples')
    # compare input of $i with next in list {$i+1} (ex. Compare 'Apples' to 'Oranges', save output)
    # take output of this comparison and use it as an input for the next analysis of $i (ex. analyze 'Apples' some more, save output for the next step, analyze data on 'Oranges')
    # save this output as the input for next script which analyses the next item in the list {$i+1}  (Analysis of 'Oranges' with input data from 'Apples', and comparing to 'Grapes' in the middle of the loop, etc., etc.)
done
```

Would it be easiest for me to provide a tabular input list in a while loop? I would really prefer not to do this as I would have to do some code editing, albeit minor.

Thanks for helping a novice -- I've looked all over the interwebs and ran through a bunch of books and haven't found a good way to do this.

EDIT: For some reason I was thinking there might have been a for loop trick to do this but I guess not; it's probably easier for me to do a while loop with a tabular input.  I was prepared to do this, but I didn't want to re-write the code I had already.

UPDATE: Thank you all so much for your time and input!  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want a recursive function, but i don't understand your instructions very well. Please post actual commands in the body of the loop, even if they are basic.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Why look at the *next* item? This requires `peek()`-type functionality, which bash doesn't have. By contrast, it's easy to look at the *previous* item -- just store it in a variable and refer to that variable in your loop. :)

Comment: Do you want your pairs to overlap? That is, `1 2`, `2 3`, `3 4`, or `1 2`, `3 4`, `5 6`?

Comment: Interesting that this has received upvotes while it remains unclear what is being asked for...Josh, please [edit] your question to address the comments requesting clarification.

Comment: Change your strategy, do not use current and next, but current and pass one. it is the same result, but easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want your values to overlap -- meaning that a value given as `next` then becomes `curr` on the following iteration.

Assuming you encapsulate your code in a function that takes two arguments (current and next) when a next item exists, or one argument when on the last item:

```
# a "higher-order function"; it takes another function as its argument
# and calls that argument with current/next input pairs.
invokeWithNext() {
  local funcName=$1
  local curr next

  read -r curr
  while read -r next; do
    "$funcName" "$curr" "$next"
    curr=$next
  done
  "$funcName" "$curr"
}

# replace this with your own logic
yourProcess() {
  local curr=$1 next=$2
  if (( $# > 1 )); then
    printf 'Current value is %q, and next item is %q\n' "$curr" "$next"
  else
    printf 'Current value is %q; no next item exists\n' "$curr"
  fi
}
```

These definitions done, you can run:

```
invokeWithNext yourProcess <list.txt
```

...yield output such as:

```
Current value is 1, and next item is 2
Current value is 2, and next item is 3
Current value is 3, and next item is 4
Current value is 4, and next item is 5
Current value is 5; no next item exists
```

Comment: (Aside: A previous version of this worked more like a traditional reducer, with a specified initial value which could be passed in; on rethinking the specification I took that functionality out, but anyone curious could look at the edit history).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use bash arrays. For example, given a file `list.txt` with content:

```
1
2
3
4
4
5
```

You can create an array variable with the lines of the file as elements as:

```
$ myarray=(1 2 3 4 4 5)
```

While you could also do `myarray=( $(echo list.txt) )` this may split on whitespace and handle other output inappropriately, the better method is:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a myarray < list.txt
```

Then you can access elements as:

```
$ echo "${myarray[2]}"
3
```

To length of the array is given by `${#myarray[@]}`. A list of all indices is given by `${!myarray[@]}`, and you can loop over this list of indices:

```
for i in "${!myarray[@]}"; do 
    echo "${myarray[$i]} ${myarray[$(( $i + 1))]}" 
done
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 4
4 5
5
```

While there are likely simpler solutions to your particular use case, this would allow you to access arbitrary combinations of array elements in the loop.

Comment: `arr=( $(cat foo) )` is an antipattern for loading data into arrays; it word-splits lines and expands globs. Much better to use `readarray -t` or `mapfile -t` if on bash 4, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -a arr <foo` or a `array=( ); while read -r; do array+=( "$REPLY" ); done` loop on bash 3.

Comment: ...also, `seq` is not only not part of bash, it's also not part of POSIX, so it's completely nonportable. If you want to iterate over array indexes, use `for idx in "${!array[@]}"`; this also fixes support for sparse arrays, which doing numeric iteration will fail badly with.

Comment: Also, don't use all-caps names for variables that aren't builtins or environment variables. See the naming convention for environment variables in the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (fourth paragraph), and keep in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ printf '%d\n' {0..10} | paste - -
0   1
2   3
4   5
6   7
8   9
10
```

So if you just want to interpolate lines so that you can read two variables per line...

```
while read -r odd even; do
    …
done < <(paste - - < inputfile)
```

You will need to do additional work if your lines contain whitespace.

Comment: I read the question as expecting `0 1`, `1 2`, `2 3`, as opposed to splitting into pairs -- if a "next" item never becomes a "current" item, then it's hardly "next", is it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy SO is much more interesting when questions are up for interpretation! -_- Anyway, I kinda think Olof's answer is on a better track.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the for loop with a `while read xx` loop.
Something along the lines of

```
cat list.txt | while read line; do
  if read nextline; then
     # You have $line and $nextline
  else
     # You have garbage in $nextline and the last line of list.txt in $line
  fi
done
```

Comment: The question is whether we want to run on `1 2`, `3 4`, etc., or `1 2`, `2 3`, `3 4`, etc; I have the latter interpretation of the question, but this script does the former.

Comment: I would replace the `cat list.txt | while read` with `done < list.txt`.

Comment: @TomFenech: Yes, that's better, saving a fork/exec.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Reading the question again, I think your interpretation is correct :-)

Comment: Heh. Apparently it wasn't, and what the OP really wanted was indeed to read in non-overlapping pairs. :)

Comment: The change Tom suggested doesn't just save a fork/exec -- much more importantly, it ensures that your loop *can actually set variables the rest of your script can use*. See [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).